# Apparmor.. What we can understand through logs?

Tags: log, apparmor

```
Jan  1 09:39:14 amik-soc-pc kernel: [  997.175974] audit: type=1400 audit(1672544354.292:83): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.notepad-plus-plus.notepad-plus-plus" name="/sys/devices/system/node/online" pid=6999 comm="wine64" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

Please help me explain the above log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `apparmor = denied` AppArmor based on a profile, denied something.
- `operation="open"` The kind of operation AppArmor denied, in our case, this is probably a file.
- `profile="snap.notepad-plus-plus.notepad-plus-plus"` The profile that made AppArmor deny this.
- `name="/sys/devices/system/node/online"` The file that something was trying to open.
- `pid=6999` The PID of the process, which tried to open the file.
- `comm="wine64"` The name of the process that tried to access the file.
- `requested_mask="r"` Wine64 wanted to "r" the file. (r is for reading.)
- `denied_mask="r"` What AppArmor stopped it from doing.

AppArmor is to prevent compromised processes from running and preventing them from doing things they shouldn't be doing.

What happened is,
Wine64 wanted to read "/sys/devices/system/node/online" but AppArmor thought that "/sys/devices/system/node/online" is nothing of business for Wine64, (as per Wine64's profile).

EDIT: I'm a new contributor and my answer may be, incorrect, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: Thank you very much.. it seems reasonable now

Comment: @AmiqulIslamAmik I'm glad, I could help.